# How to get second, third and more values from string with fields separated by commas?

Tags: sql, substring

```
declare @v varchar(max) = '1,11,111,1111'
```

I need output like this (in separate lines):

```
    1
   11
  111
 1111
```

I am able to get the first and the last using:

```
    select Substring(@v,0,CharIndex(',',@v)) 
    select substring(@v, CHARINDEX(',', @v, CHARINDEX(',', @v, CHARINDEX(',', @v)+1)+1)+1, len(@v))
```

But, how can I get the second and third substrings separately?

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace...

```
declare @v varchar(max) = '1,11,111,1111' 
select replace(@v,',',' ')
```

If you are looking for multiple rows then

```
--For SQL Server >= 2016
select * from string_split(@v,',')

--For any version of sql server
DECLARE @xml as xml
SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@v,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)
SELECT  N.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)') as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)
```

Comment: actually i need output like   first line  1,second line 11,third line 111,fourth line 1111

Comment: which version of sql server?

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: thanks you for your help